# Nominate a guest for the Stack Overflow podcast

Tags: discussion, blog, podcast

Our Director of Public Q&A has [requested nominations](https://twitter.com/SaraJChipps/status/1191360220838211589?s=09) on Twitter for guests for the [Stack Overflow podcast!](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/)

[image: Screenshot of tweet]

Who should we nominate?

Note: This post is an effort on my part to share this request with our community and encourage some discussion. To be clear, I'm just a user. Answering this question doesn't nominate anyone.

Comment: @Tinkerbell the Stack Overflow podcast addresses issues for the entire network. SE meta is the site to discuss network-wide issues. Why did you migrate this from SE meta to SO meta?

Comment: @Tinkerbell There is no SE podcast, but that is in effect what the Stack Overflow podcast is. Just like there is no SE blog, but that is in effect what the Stack Overflow blog is. It's network wide, not restricted to programming.

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica "The Stack Overflow podcast is a weekly conversation about working in software development, learning to code, and the art and culture of computer programming." Sounds pretty strictly related to programming/SO to me.

Comment: Ah, see my comment under your original: it seems the podcast isn't for network issues from it's description [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/), so it should get better nominations here, the people that know the interesting people in software development, learning to code and computer programming are here, after all.

Comment: .... inviting nominations from us or Twitter?

Comment: @canon it was posted on Twitter so one would assume Twitter. However, Twitter is a public site so...

Comment: @Tinkerbell topics have included: an interview with the CEO, how to be a better feminist...

Comment: @Script47 yeah, but Twitter feedback is considerably more valuable.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Banners promoting the podcast are [displayed on all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334137/351462). I'd argue that makes it relevant to the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Is this official?

Comment: @JL2210 the tweet is official, the post is to loop the community in

Comment: @Rubiksmoose The irony is on behalf of Sara for avoiding the community and favouring Twitter once again. In all the effort she put into making this a more _inclusive_ place, she forgot to include herself.

Comment: I don't use Twitter (and don't have any plans to do so), so I would never have seen that announcement.  Stack Exchange making announcements on Twitter makes about as much sense as Trump making announcements on Twitter.  Which is to say, none at all.

Comment: @Robert, on the other hand, it gives us a strong hint about who the expected audience of these podcasts are, and the place where you can find them (hint: *not here*).

Comment: @RobertHarvey But Twitter is such a lovely place comparing to Meta... Actually, not, but you can easily block people who disagree with you and enjoy in your cozy bubble.

Answer (score 161):

[Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio)

Comment: She did write the SEDE tutorial so if it needs to be about dev stuff, make it about technical writing. That alone would be an epic podcast.

Comment: While this is a very tempting idea, and I upvoted, I doubt SE would go for that now that she has consulted with a lawyer. I mean, they wouldn't talk to her before, why would they want a fireside chat now?

Comment: @JonHarper why shouldn't people vote for her if they want to hear her?

Comment: @Sklivvz Didn't say they shouldn't. Only that it's highly unlikely given the circumstances.

Answer (score 42):

The intended audience of that tweet is explicitly not Meta Stack Overflow, and I for one lack the stamina to make this another point of conflict between MSO and staffers.

Phrased in another manner:  if the Stack Overflow Podcast wanted someone from this community to be a guest speaker, they'd reach out to someone from this community in addition to posting it on Twitter, as opposed to *just* posting it on Twitter.

In fairness I haven't really listened to the podcasts - kinda stopped ever since Joel stopped - so I'm not entirely clear on their goal anymore.  For a while it seemed like they were more about programming *and* the overall Stack Exchange network to a degree; now I'm unclear.

So, who should we nominate as a guest?  **No one.**
I say we let this one be.

Comment: I'm not sure why nominations from the community would be limited to someone from the community. For example, Sid Sijbrandij.

Comment: Also, why would a discussion about who Stack Overflow users would like to hear on the Stack Overflow podcast be a point of conflict?

Comment: Hmm... Invite Joel back for another podcast?

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica:  My train of thought is strikingly simple on this one.  Had a Meta post never been created about this, then someone could've informed Stack Overflow via Twitter that Sid Sijbrandij would make a great podcast guest.  By making it a Meta post, we now get some signal like *that* and a lot more noise than I feel is worth anyone's time to filter out.  I am content to let Twitter outreach live on its own and not let Twitter and MSO mix more than absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 32):

I'd like to nominate Sid Sijbrandij, the CEO and co-founder of GitLab.

Comment: might have some interesting stories to tell about listing to users

Comment: Link for the uninitiated: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/34833

Comment: This answer should link the article @Script47 mentioned.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I wanted to keep it as neutral as possible, in the hope that the answer itself will survive and just the comments get deleted.

Comment: @samcarter Sad that offering the reason for your answer makes you fear its deletion.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/issues/5555

Answer (score 32):

It has been suggested that Monica Cellio be nominated, but that's likely a non-starter due to [things] and SE's...[more things].

**I nominate the community for this podcast. All questions will be submitted ahead of time and voted upon, then answered in the podcast.**

This is an entirely unofficial process, but at least by prepping questions, finding the most suitable (and discarding off-topic, non-technical questions), and offering them *outside the context of Meta*, maybe just maybe, we might start a reasonable *technical* discussion *that is on-topic for the podcast*.

At some point, SE staff and the community need to rebuild some lines of communication. Let's start here.

Edit: [I've made this in to a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391047/nominate-a-question-for-the-stack-overflow-podcast)

Comment: *All questions will be submitted ahead of time and voted upon* What do you think, what question would get the most upvotes? *SE staff and the community need to rebuild some lines of communication. Let's start here.* This is exactly what SE is hoping, that the community would eventually let the current issues fade, and they can pretend that nothing has happened. Move along, there's nothing to see here.

Comment: @berendi-protesting It is my sincere hope that we can have a technical discussion on one avenue where technical discussions are part and parcel, while continuing to find ways to address SE's behavior in a constructive manner. i.e. We need to stop angrily navel-gazing and yelling into an echo chamber. For all we know, SE doesn't even look at Meta anymore, and sitting and stewing is getting us nowhere, fast.

Comment: We're so caught up in our righteous outrage that we can't see an opportunity to *organize as a community* and present a proposal to SE *that isn't centered around hostility*.

Comment: @JonHarper:  Mind kicking us off? I'm blocked mentally on this too.

Comment: @Makoto I...uh...dang. Beat the drum loud enough and someone asks you to keep time, I guess. Sure, I think I'll cook up a Q.

Comment: I've now [made this into a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391047/nominate-a-question-for-the-stack-overflow-podcast/391048). @Makoto

Answer (score 16):

I would like to nominate [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray). I recently was surprised at his intricate knowledge of x86 assembly when he provided a link to [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213558) on one of my questions, with this surrounding context:

> @JL2210 You might be interested in this answer, which discusses ways of optimizing strlen using basic x86 instructions (i.e., without using any SSE). A similar approach could be used for memchr, except that you can't optimize so heavily around searching for a 0-byte. Certainly, as Peter says, SSE is the way to make it really fast. I've written and benchmarked that code, too. If you want to know more, ask more questions about it. I could expand that answer another 10 pages, but I'd eventually run out of room and folks would tire of reading. – Cody Gray ♦

It was a very interesting read and I (and possibly others) would be interested in learning more in the podcast (i.e. discussing possible `strcmp` implementations, which was missing from the answer).

Comment: I'll second this nomination, but include that I'd like to hear his experiences in moderating this site through these troubled times and how he's managed to keep a relatively cool head.