# Nominate a Question for the Stack Overflow Podcast

Tags: discussion, podcast

This is a follow-up to [Nominate a guest for the Stack Overflow podcast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391028/nominate-a-guest-for-the-stack-overflow-podcast), and specifically my answer to that question. Actually, it's more a response to a request by Makoto to do this. So here goes:

In my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391038/4732082) to the aforementioned question, I suggested we draw up a list of **technical** questions, suitable for an SO podcast, presented as a community-voted list. It's their podcast, but our opportunity to be a community again.

### Why would we do that?

Because I'm out of eloquence for the day, I'll quote myself:

> It is my sincere hope that we can have a technical discussion on one avenue where technical discussions are part and parcel, while continuing to find ways to address SE's behavior in a constructive manner [elsewhere]. i.e. We need to stop angrily navel-gazing and yelling into an echo chamber. For all we know, SE doesn't even look at Meta anymore, and sitting and stewing is getting us nowhere, fast.
>
> We're so caught up in our <strike>righteous</strike> outrage that we can't see an opportunity to *organize as a community* and present a proposal to SE that isn't *centered around hostility*.

### But we're angry...

I know, a lot is going on right now. I'm angry/frustrated. You're angry/frustrated. We're all tense and snippy. There is a time and [place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to voice your frustration and outrage. There is also a time and place to reach out our hands and see if the other side will, even tentatively, take hold. **Does the SE staff still visit Meta? Let's make a good-faith effort to find out.**

It's their podcast, but our opportunity to be a community again.

### Okay, so what can I ask?

Non-technical questions put forward will not be considered, no matter how highly upvoted. In fact, if curation is called for to *remove* answers with off-topic questions, I would see that self-policing as a net positive. **To be completely clear, such questions would never make it in the podcast in the first place, so let us not waste our keystrokes.**

I'm fairly interested in JL2210's suggestion that we poke at Cody Gray's brain a bit about x86 assembly optimizations. That's a starting point. I'm *sure* Shog9 has some seriously cool stuff we could ask. But, hey, it doesn't even *have* to be moderators or SE developers answering these questions. In fact, the questions can be open-ended and opinion-based, things you *can't* ask on SO.

- <strike>That one question</strike>Those thirty questions that got 1000 upvotes and the top-voted answer is completely wrong? Ask about one.
- Then there's that question about [finding a Coca-Cola can in a photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition). What new technologies have evolved in the past 7.5 years to assist? Ask about it.
- What is SE's perspective on machine learning to identify duplicate questions? Ask about it.

### Who will answer these questions?

I don't make up the podcast visitor list, so who knows? We might get SE to invite some well known names from the community or SMEs (Subject Matter Experts) in certain areas from outside the community.

**It's their podcast, but our opportunity to be a community again.**

Comment: If you want an x86 optimization wizard who will blow your mind, you want [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) or [Agner Fog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862391/a-fog), not me. I'm a lightweight.

Comment: @CodyGray What would you ask them if you could, even if it were too broad or opinion-based for SO?

Comment: I've been here so long, my brain is conditioned to not even think of questions that are too broad or opinion-based.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to hear a dive into C++ in the microcontroller world, as I'm currently working with AVR:

- **What is the future of C++ with respect to toolchains that still rely on C++98 and C++11, e.g. Arduino, Atmel Studio?**

  - How will the increasing size and complexity of the Standard Library even in freestanding installations impede uptake?
  - What are other impediments to having modern compiler features on platforms like AVR?

<sub>Note: I've deleted the sample answer, as I woke up with a legitimate question on my mind</sub>

Comment: Just switch to a GCC-based toolchain: better optimizer, more modern C++ support, free and open-source. What are the disadvantages?

Comment: @CodyGray Huh? Atmel (and thus Arduino) use gcc.